# Is it a bad design decision to manually call the destructor in the following case?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, destructor

so I am currently working on my OOP/C++ skills and stumbled upon the following case:

I am making a game which is populated by entities, which have to eat in order to survive. They can either eat other entities or food. In order to achieve this behaviour I created an `edible` interface which forces every implementing class to create a `getNutritionalInformation()` method to calculate how saturated a unit will be after feasting.

So the whole thing is supposed to work like this code-wise:

```
std::unique_ptr<Entity> e1(new Entity);
std::unique_ptr<Entity> e2(new Entity);

std::cout << "Pre feasting energy: " << e1->getNutritionalInformation() << std::endl;
e1->eat(*e2);
std::cout << "After feasting energy: " << e1->getNutritionalInformation() << std::endl;
```

After this operation `c1`s energy should be higher than before, this value is currently randomly assigned during creation of an entity. But in order to simulate the *death* of the eaten entity I want to manually *kill* it while it is being eaten. I achieved this the following way:

```
void Entity::eat(Edible& subject) {
   this->energy += subject.getNutritionalInformation();
   delete &subject;
}
```

But in the end this simply seems kind of dirty to me, I would really like to let the smart pointer know in some way, that the object it currently holds/points to is not valid any longer. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? I am pretty sure the way I am trying to do this is very hacky and not considered proper OOP programming.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Why not call `reset` on the `unique_ptr` which clears the pointer and destroys the object it pointed to?

Comment: This isn't really related to your question so I put it as a comment, but FYI while smart pointers are the preferred way to handle heap allocations, even more preferred is not to use the heap at all. Unless you have inheritance hierarchy (which may or may not be a good idea) with `Entity` as the base, it would just be preferable to create local variables on the stack instead of using pointers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, by `e2` "eating" `e1` it is actually taking ownership of it. Specifically, it has to take ownership of it, in order to destroy it. So the way to do it is actually this:

```
void Entity::eat(std::unique_ptr<Edible> subject) {
    this->energy += subject->getNutritionalInformation();
}
```

And... that's it. the subject will automatically be destroyed at the end of scope. In order to use this, you'll need to call `std::move` explicitly; this indicates that you are *transferring* ownership from the calling scope, into e2.

```
std::unique_ptr<Entity> e1(new Entity);
std::unique_ptr<Entity> e2(new Entity);

std::cout << "Pre feasting energy: " << e1->getNutritionalInformation() << std::endl;
e1->eat(std::move(e2));
std::cout << "After feasting energy: " << e1->getNutritionalInformation( << std::endl;
```

Note that after `std::move` has been called on `e2`, `e2` can no longer be assumed to actually point to an entity (since ownership has been transferred).

Comment: Or, pass the `std::unique_ptr` by reference to `eat()`, and then `eat()` can call `reset()` on it, thus still destroying the object without having to actually take ownership of it, or needing the caller to `std::move()` to transfer ownership. `void Entity::eat(std::unique_ptr<Edible> &subject) { energy += subject->getNutritionalInformation(); subject.reset(); }` ... `e1->eat(e2);`

Answer (score 1):

You want the owner of `e2` to call `delete` on its variable to prevent problems down the line.

You can accomplish this in two ways:

```
e1->eat(std::move(e2));
void Entity::eat(std::unique_ptr<Edible> subject) {
    this->energy += subject->getNutritionalInformation();
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
e1->eat(*e2);
e2.reset(nullptr);
```

In either case your caller (the function in your first example) knows that `e2` is being destroyed by the operation, in the first instance I gave that is because you moved out of it, in the second because it manually called `reset` (which destroys the old pointer).

Answer (score 1):

An object's destructor is called automatically when `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope.  You don't need to worry about it.

Manually destroying an object may cause problems.  In this case, when `eat()` manually destroys the `subject` object, the `std::unique_ptr` which owns that object does not know the object has been destroyed, and will crash when it tries to destroy the object again a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plese don't manually do it.
This one of the few things that you actually do *not* have to care about. Your program does that for you!
The rule is: once a variable leaves the scope, it get's thrown away (desconstructor get's called). Except for dynamic allocated memory, there you need to free (delte) the variable/s.

Also if you manually delete a variable, your program crashes:

```
{
    Type variable;
    delete variable;
} //Scope end: deconstructor get's called. ERROR: already deleated, undefined behaviour, crash. everything destroyed.
```

Comment: Sadly you did not answer my question. I already know that this is bad, but I do not want to _wait_ for my eaten entity to run out of scope. If it is consumed by another entity it should die and be removed from the memory. Otherwise a entity could be eaten multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Other way around is to have some higher level manager controlling life cycles of entities, so the e2 during eat would do only: e1->kill(); e1->eatenEnergy(energy); (lowering it's nutritional value, if partly eaten entities are possible).

And wait till the entities manager gets its turn, to cycle trough all entities (or react to reported signals, like death event from inside e1->kill() implementation) and releasing those which are dead and completely eaten/decayed/etc (killing those which are hungry, ...).

Depends a lot if you want to keep in the simple event-based world like your current example, or you want some "life cycles" to happen in the world, while the [memory/instance] management is centralized in single class.

I think centralized managers would complicate things a bit, but then some possibilities should be easier with them, like better debug-check of initial/end state of turn, prioritize some entities processing, reuse memory of entities (w/o dynamic allocation), etc..

In both cases you should thing ahead, how some corner-case situations (mostly race conditions) will be resolved, like:

- e1 is wanting to eat e2 at the same time, as e2 wants to eat e1
- both e1 and e3 wants to eat e2 at the same time
- e3 trying to eat e2 after it was already eaten by e1 (e2 is "dead" but allocated)

So the state of entities should be designed to be valid in such situation, and ending in desired result.